# Android widget code

Tags: java, android, file

Anyone have any comments? Just trying to better my code if can be done.

```
public class SacWidget extends AppWidgetProvider {
    String roseUrl;
    AQuery aq;

    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
            int[] appWidgetIds) {
        final int N = appWidgetIds.length;
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            int appWidgetId = appWidgetIds[i];
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, DangerRose.class);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
                    intent, 0);
            RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),
                    R.layout.widget_layout);
            views.setImageViewBitmap(R.id.ivdangerrose, getRose());
            appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);
        }
    }

    private Bitmap getRose() {
        Bitmap bitmap = null;
        File f = new File("/storage/emulated/0/acr/sac/dangerrose.png");
        try {
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new FileInputStream(f));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return bitmap;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not too familiar with Android, so the following is just some generic Java notes:

1. Fields `roseUrl` and `aq` seem unused as well as the `pendingIntent` local variable. You might remove them.
2. You could use a foreach loop:

   ```
   for (final int appWidgetId: appWidgetIds) ...
   ```
3. [It isn't the best idea to use `printStackTrace()` in Android exceptions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3855187/843804).
4. The `getRose()` method creates a stream (`new FileInputStream(f)`). I'm not sure whether `BitmapFactory.decodeStream` closes it before it returns or not. If not, you should close it.

Notes for the edit:

1. You should close the stream in a `finally` block. If `BitmapFactory.decodeStream` throws an exception it won't be closed. See *Guideline 1-2: Release resources in all cases* in [Secure Coding Guidelines for the Java Programming Language](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/seccodeguide-139067.html)
2. The following two lines are duplicated:

   ```
   File ext = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
   File file = new File(ext,"acr/sac/dangerrose.png");
   ```

   You could extract them out to a method.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I really appreciate it. I cleaned up the code a bit. I cannot find a close for the IS in any of the documentation.... hmmmm....

Answer (score 2):

1. Bad variable names.  Please do not use things like `N`, `i`, and `f` (and if you are, at least be consistent and make them all lowercase).  That `aq` is questionable as well.
2. Using `for (int appWidgetId : appWidgetIds)` would save you a couple lines, and get rid of that atrocious `i` and `N` variables as well.
3. Personally I wouldn't bother declaring `N` as `final` (or at all, since you could just as easily use `appWidgetIds.length` in your `for` loop condition even if you don't do #2) unless there is reason to.  Like if you're going to refer to it from an anonymous class.  Note that if you do #2 above, `N` goes away completely.
4. Close your `FileInputStream`.  Instead of doing `File f = ...` do `FileInputStream input = new FileInputStream(new File("/storage/..."));` and then `input.close();` when you are done with it.