# Homescreen Widget Service

Tags: java, android

I have implemented changes from a question I asked on this widget here:

[Android widget code](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/21131/android-widget-code-review)

I've added and changed a few things, so I would love some more coding advice!

```
public class SacWidgetService extends Service {
    private static final String TAG = "SAC WIDGET SERVICE";
    AQuery aq;
    private String roseXML = "sac-full.xml";
    private String roseUrl;
    private AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager;
    private int[] allWidgetIds;
    private File ext;
    private File file;

    @Override
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {

        aq = new AQuery(this);
        // Create some random data
        appWidgetManager = AppWidgetManager.getInstance(this
                    .getApplicationContext());

        allWidgetIds = intent.getIntArrayExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS);

        // get external directory and put the file in there.
        ext = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        file = new File(ext, "avalancheconditionsreport/sac/dangerrose.png");

        // parse xml and get the rose
        xml_ajax();

        stopSelf();

        super.onStart(intent, startId);
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    public void xml_ajax() {
        aq.ajax(roseXML, XmlDom.class, this, "sacCb");
    }

    public void sacCb(String url, XmlDom xml, AjaxStatus status) {
        XmlDom r = xml.tag("reportrose");
        roseUrl = r.tag("img").attr("src").trim();

        File ext = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        File target = new File(ext,
                "avalancheconditionsreport/sac/dangerrose.png");

        aq.download(roseUrl, target, new AjaxCallback<File>() {
            public void callback(String url, File file, AjaxStatus status) {
                String s = status.getMessage();
                int i = status.getCode();
                String e = s + " | Status Code: " + i;

                if (file != null) {
                    getInfo();
                } else {
                    Log.e("ACR SAC Widget Error", e);
                }
            }

        });
    }

    private Bitmap getRose() {
        Bitmap bitmap = null;
        try {
            FileInputStream input = new FileInputStream(file);
            bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
            try {
                input.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
            }
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
        }
        // Toast.makeText(this, "Sierra Avalanche Center Danger Rose",
        // Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return bitmap;

    }

    private void getInfo() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Date dlm = new Date(file.lastModified());
        String lm = dlm.toLocaleString();

        for (int appWidgetId : allWidgetIds) {
            RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(this.getApplicationContext()
                    .getPackageName(), R.layout.sac_widget_layout);

            Intent clickIntent = new Intent(this.getApplicationContext(),
                    SACActivity.class);
            PendingIntent clickapp = PendingIntent.getActivity(
                        this.getApplicationContext(), 0, clickIntent,
                        PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

            views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.ivdangerrose, clickapp);
            views.setTextViewText(R.id.tvupdated, "Updated: " + lm);
            views.setImageViewBitmap(R.id.ivdangerrose, getRose());
            appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);
        }
    }        
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. > ```
   > try {
   >     FileInputStream input = new FileInputStream(file);
   >     bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
   >     try {
   >         input.close();
   >     } catch (IOException e) {
   >         // TODO Auto-generated catch block
   >         Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
   >     }
   > } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
   >     Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
   > }
   > ```

   If `decodeStream` throws an exception the stream won't be closed. A proper solution is the following:

   ```
   try {
       FileInputStream input = new FileInputStream(file);
       try {
           bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
       } finally {
           input.close();
       }
   } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
       Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
   } catch (IOException e) {
       Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
   }
   ```

   Or this:

   ```
   try {
       FileInputStream input = new FileInputStream(file);
       try {
           bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
       } finally {
           input.close();
       }
   } catch (IOException e) {
       Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
   }
   ```

   (Since `FileNotFoundException` is a subclass of `IOException`).
2. > ```
   > AQuery aq;
   > ```

   I guess this field could be `private`. ([Should I always use the private access modifier for class fields?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5484845/should-i-always-use-the-private-access-modifier-for-class-fields); *Item 13* of *Effective Java 2nd Edition*: *Minimize the accessibility of classes and members*.)
3. > ```
   > private String roseUrl;
   > ...
   > private File ext;
   > ```

   These field is used only in one method (`onStart` and `sacCb`). They could be local variables instead. (*Effective Java, Second Edition, Item 45: Minimize the scope of local variables*)
4. > ```
   > public void xml_ajax() {
   > ```

   This method name does not follow the usual `camelCase` conventions and it should be a verb. From [Code Conventions for the Java Programming Language](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html#367):

   > Methods should be verbs, in mixed case with the first letter
   >   lowercase, with the first letter of each internal word capitalized.
5. I'd use longer and more descriptive variable names (which explains their purpose) for better readability than this ones:

   > ```
   > XmlDom r = xml.tag("reportrose");
   > ...
   > String s = status.getMessage();
   > int i = status.getCode();
   > String e = s + " | Status Code: " + i;
   > ...
   > String lm = dlm.toLocaleString();
   > ```

   Longer names would make the code more readable since readers don't have to decode the abbreviations every time and when they write/maintain the code don't have to guess which abbreviation the author uses.
6. > ```
   > private Bitmap getRose() {
   >     Bitmap bitmap = null;
   >     try {
   >         FileInputStream input = new FileInputStream(file);
   >         try {
   >             bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
   >         } finally {
   >             input.close();
   >         }
   >     } catch (IOException e) {
   >         Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
   >     }
   >     return bitmap;
   > }
   > ```

   You can get rid of the bitmap variable here if you return immediately:

   ```
   private Bitmap getRose() {
       try {
           FileInputStream input = new FileInputStream(file);
           try {
               return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
           } finally {
               input.close();
           }
       } catch (IOException e) {
           Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
       }
       return null;
   }
   ```

   See *Guideline 1-2: Release resources in all cases* in [Secure Coding Guidelines for the Java Programming Language](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/seccodeguide-139067.html)
7. > ```
   > String lm = dlm.toLocaleString();
   > ```

   This method is deprecated, you should use something else.
8. > ```
   > // TODO Auto-generated catch block
   > ```

   Comments like this doesn't seem like professional work. Solve the issues and remove the comments.